# Question about cache in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, caching

**I wonder if selector "$cacheA" will be cached on page load in the example below?**

```
// MY JQUERY FUNCTION/PLUGIN
(function( $ ){
$.fn.myFunction = function() {

var $cacheA = this,
$cacheB = $cacheA.children(),
$cacheC = $cacheB.eq(0);
$cacheD = $cacheA.parent();    

$cacheD.click(function(){

$cacheA.toggle();
$cacheB.fadeIn();
$cacheC.slideUp();

});

};
})( jQuery );
// END JQUERY FUNCTION/PLUGIN



$(window).load(function(){

$('#mySelector').myFunction();

});
```

**Would it be any reason to do this:**

```
$(window).load(function(){

var $mySelector = $('#mySelector');

$mySelector.myFunction();

});
```

Comment: If $cacheA is cached I assume that $cacheB, $cacheC and $cacheD will also be cached at page load?

Comment: This question makes no sense.  What do you mean, "cached"?

Comment: With "cache" I mean: By saving the selector in a variable the browser only have to do doom travel once. This will speed up the script if the selector is useed multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, inside your "load" handler, you were to do many jQuery operations with "$mySelector", then saving that in a variable would be a good idea.  However, in your example, you only use the value once, so it really makes no difference at all.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. The $mySelector will be used in the jquery function. See "var $cacheA = this". Will it make any difference then?

Comment: +1 Caching is only valuable when you're traversing the DOM over and over again with the same selector.

Comment: No - if you save the `$('#something')` value, then you can re-use it many times.  Inside your jQuery plugin "myFunction", it will be the value of `this`. However, the variables "$cacheB", "$cacheC", and so on, are all local variables, and they will be re-computed every time you call "myFunction", even if you call it with the same starting jQuery object ("$mySelector").

Answer (score 0):

Firstable, $cacheA and others inside click function will be undefined.

```
$cacheD.click(function(){

$cacheA.toggle();
$cacheB.fadeIn();
$cacheC.slideUp();

});
```

Second,

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() {

var $cacheA = this,
$cacheB = $cacheA.children(),
$cacheC = $cacheB.eq(0);
$cacheD = $cacheA.parent();
}
```

So, after `$('selector').myFunction()` how can I use $cacheB, $cacheC and $cacheD? Where they are will store?